# Android studio: messy native logcat output

Tags: android-studio, native, android-logcat

On the Android Studio logcat window i often get annoying displaced lines. This is an example output:

```
line1

                                                             [ 11-03 13:58:43.164 19597:30028 I/C:/android/android-studio-workspace/.........
line2
```

Every wrongly indented line starts with the '[' character. The following is a correct log line:

```
11-03 16:15:18.883 26517-26517/com.me.myapp I/C:/android/android-studio-workspace/.../jni/code.cpp:515: Hello there!
```

This is an incorrect log message:

```
              [ 11-03 16:15:19.000 26517:26517 I/C:/android/android-studio-workspace/.../jni/code.cpHello there!
```

I have a `common.h` file where i define the LOGI macro:

```
void    custom_log( const char *log_tag, const char *format, ... );
#define STRINGIFY2(x) #x
#define STRINGIFY(x) STRINGIFY2(x)
#define LOG_TAG __FILE__ ":" STRINGIFY(__LINE__)
#define LOGI(...)   custom_log( LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__ )
```

The `custom_log()` routine is defined in a file called `common.cpp`:

```
#include    <android/log.h>
void    custom_log( const char *log_tag, const char *format, ... )
{
    va_list args;
    va_start( args, format );
    __android_log_vprint ( ANDROID_LOG_INFO, log_tag, format, args );
    va_end (args);
}
```

Could it be that native code messages are fired too quickly?